# python zeros array based on another : same shape but longer along one dimension

Tags: python, numpy

I have variables which number of dimensions can be any value greater than 2. for each variable I would like to initialise a new variable with zeros with the same shape but longer along the first dimension, i.e. 10 times longer.

```
import numpy as np
variable = np.ones([4, 5, 6])    #  This is just an example; in reality variable is generated
                                 #+ from data contained in files with np.genfromtxt, and the
                                 #+ number of dimensions can be anything greater than two

new_var = np.zeros([variable.shape[0] * 10, variable[0].shape])
                                 #  my above attempt does not work because variable[0].shape
                                 #+ returns a tuple and the result of what's given as argument
                                 #+ to np.zeros is [4, (5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can simply concatenate tuples:

```
>>> v = np.ones([4,5,6])
>>> new_v = np.zeros((v.shape[0]*10,)+v.shape[1:])
>>> new_v.shape
(40, 5, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to take care when constructing the shape tuple:

```
new_shape = (variable.shape[0] * 10,) + variable.shape[1:]
```

Then you can do

```
new_var = np.zeros(new_shape)
```